# assert a mocked static method is called multiple times each with a specific argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, powermockito

**Not a duplicate**
I already looked at [Mocking static method that is called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16145359/14309129), that question, however, is different from mine in that he is seeking *partial mocking*.

**What I want**

```java
class A {
   public static void a(int x, int y);   // <-- mock this static method
}
```

How do I mock the `a(x,y)` method?

Pseudo code for what I want my test to do:

```java
class TestA {
    @Test
    public void test_method_a_is_called_x_numbers_of_times_each_with_specific_parameters() {
        SUT.exercise()  // I need to verify SUT's behavior by observing the SUT's calls to `a(x,y)`

        // I want to somehow be able to assert: (Psuedo code)
        // First  call to `a(x,y)` was:   a(0,0)
        // Second call to `a(x,y)` was:   a(0,1)
        // Third  call to `a(x,y)` was:   a(0,0)
        // Fourth call to `a(x,y)` was:   a(4,2)

        // You get the idea ...
    }
}
```

Comment: *Why* are you mocking?  This method doesn't actually do anything to any artifact that you can actually test or observe.  If it's called then this implies that it touches some other external, static artifact that you can observe.  In this case there's absolutely nothing to observe as a side effect, and mocking gains you nothing.

Comment: @Makoto In my case, `a()` writes to a file. I would like to avoid having to deal with i/o by mocking `a()` and then asserting it's called with the expected parameters.

Comment: Files are easy, though.  In JUnit 4 you can set up a `TemporaryFolder` rule and set things up to write to that to validate that the file is being written to.  In fact that'd make for a better test overall since you can prove that the file is actually being written *and* that it has the values you care about as opposed to mocks which accomplish neither.

Comment: @Makoto My actual case is a little more complicated, and I got my reasons for temporarily abandoning just that. Im now attempting to do what my question states to see how that compares against what you just stated.

Answer (score -1):

Mockito has made it possible to mock static methods after their 3.4.0 version without external Powermock. Below are some good articles on how to achieve this.

- Article - https://wttech.blog/blog/2020/mocking-static-methods-made-possible-in-mockito-3.4.0/
- Mockito Wiki - https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.6.28/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48.

> ```
>  assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
>  try (MockedStatic mocked = mockStatic(Foo.class)) {
>     mocked.when(Foo::method).thenReturn("bar");
>     assertEquals("bar", Foo.method());
>     mocked.verify(Foo::method);
>  }
>  assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
> ```